# es sobre angular 5 un error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

```
<h4>Formularios <small>data</small></h4>
<hr>

<form [formGroup]="forma" (ngSubmit)="guardarCambios ()" novalidate="novalidate">


  <div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Nombre</label>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nombre">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Apellido</label>
      <div class="col-md-5">

        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Apellido">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Correo</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">

      <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico">
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-2 col-form-label"></label>
    <div class="input-group col-md-8">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
        Guardar
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

> Error: Template parse errors: Unexpected closing tag "form". It may
>   happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more
>   info see
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("
>
> [ERROR ->]

Comment: tendrás algún `</form>` de más ?

Comment: A simple vista y según varios validadores de `HTML` tu estructura se encuentra correcta =/ .. Cuál es el error **completo**?

Comment: el error que que me sale es esto:               Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "form". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("
  </div>

[ERROR ->]</form>

"): ng:///AppModule/TemplateComponent.html@144:0

Comment: Hola delfor te sugiero realices tus preguntas en base a [ask], agrega una explicación en el cuerpo de la pregunta, te aseguro que de esta forma obtendrás la ayuda deseada, saludos!